# SQL Server 2012 error: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use SQL Server 2012 and I have some databases on it. The problem is I suddenly get an error saying,

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I get this error when:

- Going to write a new query
- Select previously entered data by right click the table name ->
  Select top 1000 rows

What I can do without getting error message:

- Log into my instance successfully using both Windows Authentication mode and SQL Authentication mode.
- Edit the table data by right click the table name -> Edit top 200 rows
- Create a new database

I'm using:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: 11.0.3128.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.0.30319.34014
- Operating System: Windows 8.1

Here are some snapshots of the error.
[image: error]

[image: Advanced_information]

Please give me a solution to fix this problem. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This seems more of a DBA question, you may get a better response from dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try reinstalling SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Your snapshots seem vague.

Comment: @Twelfth why? Is SSMS not among [software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @wdosanjos Indeed, or a new version.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Agreed, but issue doesn't seem to be with code, rather the configuration of his database...figured he get a better response with that route

Comment: @Twelfth No, disagree 100%. This is a *client-side* error occurring in his *client-side programming tool*.

Comment: Restart SSMS to see if that helps.  If not, try rebooting your machine.  I get errors like this in Visual Studio from time to time when my computer goes through numerous sleep/wake cycles.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - very well, I'll definitely defer to your experience here.  retracted close

Comment: Upgrade it to the latest version: [x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/MgmtStudio%2064BIT/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe) / [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/MgmtStudio%2032BIT/SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe). Or wait for the download pages to come back up (they're currently down) and at least update it to 2012 SP2: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

Comment: @EricHauenstein - Sorry for the inconvenience. I have uploaded the snapshots again.

Comment: [Direct link to Management Studio for 2012 SP2 x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/E/01E0D693-2B4F-4442-9713-27A796B327BD/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe). If you have problems getting any of these versions installed, please see [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73826/can-i-install-sql-server-management-studio-locally/73919#73919).

Comment: Oh, and just FYI, we don't need to see the screen shot. Most of those dialogs support copy and paste; all we need is the text

Comment: @ps2goat - I have restarted the SSMS and reboot the machine as well. But I still get the error.

Comment: So upgrade to SP2 or the 2014 version.

Comment: @Twelfth - Thanks for you idea. I will put this same question on dba.stackexchange.com also.

Comment: No, please DO NOT post the same question to another site in this network.

Comment: no Kasun, don't repeat post.  Comments between aaron and I agree that it should be here

Comment: @AaronBertrand - ok sir. I will not repeat it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I downloaded and installed Management Studio 2012 SP2. It didn't work. 
But then I repaired SQL Server(repaired all the instances of my Server) Fortunately it works. Now the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could solve the error.
Repair the SQL Server.

Go to `Add/remove programs` `Microsoft SQL Server 2012(x64)` -> `Uninstall/Change` -> `Repair`. 
Select the instance that you want to repair here.

[image: Select the instance]

For me, after repairing the instance, the error was solved.

Thanks for all who spent their valuable time to reply my question.

Comment: After reinstalling error got resolved

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the problem by running SSMS as administrator.

Comment: I have both SqlExpress16 (X64) and SqlExpress12 (X86), the problem was presented while using sqlExpress12 (x86) and I resolved it by running SSMS without Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message. Problem was 0 bytes free on the C: drive.

Answer (score 2):

Its may be late, but i get the same error in SQL SERVER 2016, i resolved it by assigning full access to the back up folder.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error once in my project. This is purely due to SSMS(sql client) is corrupted. Just for cross check that server is fine and client is corrupted, try to connect to the sql-server in this machine from any other server if you have access and query the tables. If it returns data, just uninstall and reinstall the client(ssms) to solve the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for SQL 2016 and the only solution for me was to completely uninstall (in appwiz.cpl) all entries Visual Studio + SQL. Then I executed [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) and I reinstalled SQL and after Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when I try to alter table to add new column . Issue is I haven't enclosed data types using '[' datatype ']' . Its Real data type. But It got fixed when I enclosed in using square braces.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to access properties of any user under **Databases>"AnyDataBase">Security>Users**, I found that the error was purely about administrator privilegies for SMSS, I just ran it as administrator and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

My *solution* for this was to extract the csv file with the python library pandas rather than saving it with Excel. Further, I removed columns that I didn't need as a few columns caused formatting errors during the import.

Answer (score -1):

For those who are unable to modify their SQL configuration due to administrative restrictions at work:

I was able to open a new query page by creating a SQL Server Scripts project and adding a new query through the solution explorer

[image: Creating a SQL Server Scripts project and adding a new query through the solution explorer]

Answer (score -3):

I got the message after deleting a database. The database was gone, so I moved on.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I added an example of where the error occurs, just as the commentators above also gave examples. Are you suggesting that I should remove the second sentence? Or, can you help me understand how this example of the problem is any less helpful than the answers above mine?

Comment: I think the other posters, gave when it happened to them, but they also gave their solution.  But "The database was gone, so I moved on." is not helpful either. Stack overflow tends to be pretty cut throat with Q&A that are not really on topic.