# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (SQLEditors)

Tags: sql, sql-server, object

I keep getting this error every time I try and save a new view. whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" occurs because of one of the **required component** was not available on the server.

visit: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973301/fix-error-message-when-you-install-sql-server-2008-or-sql-server-2008-service-pack-1-on-a-windows-xp-based-computer-that-has-sql-server-2000-installed-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.


[SQL Server 2012 error: object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574884/sql-server-2012-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Hope  this will give you right direction .....