# SQL Server 2014 error: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, installation

when installing SQL Server 2014 i get this error :

[image]

whether installing SQL SERVER 2008,2012 or 2014
i tried this 
[SQL Server 2012 error: object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574884/sql-server-2012-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)
and many other solution on internet but it didn't resolve my problem.
please solve my problem and give in proper steps that i can follow.

Comment: What operating system version are you trying to install on?

Comment: Operating System : Windows 8.1